# change an image onload

Tags: javascript, image, onload, fade

I have a simple webpage with an image in a div on the homepage and would like to use javascript to change the image for an alternative image after the page has loaded (only once) using a slow fade, i am currently using an animated gif to do this but would prefer to use javascript.

I have limited javascript skills.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you won't use jQuery so i've created simple js eample which fades out one image and fades in other after page is loaded. You can check the example here http://jsfiddle.net/rJzPV/7/

```
function fadeOut(elem, time, callbackFn) {
    var startOpacity = elem.style.opacity || 1;
    elem.style.opacity = startOpacity;

    (function go() {
        elem.style.opacity -= startOpacity / (time / 100);

        // for IE
        elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + elem.style.opacity * 100 + ')';

        if (elem.style.opacity > 0.11)
            setTimeout(go, 100);
        else {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            if (callbackFn)
                callbackFn();
        }
    })();
}

function fadeIn(elem, time) {
    var startOpacity = 0.1;
    elem.style.opacity = startOpacity;
    elem.style.display = "";
    (function go() {
        elem.style.opacity -= -startOpacity / (time / 1000);

        // for IE
        elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + elem.style.opacity * 100 + ')';

        if (elem.style.opacity < 1)
            setTimeout(go, 100);
    })();
}

window.addEvent('load', function () {
    function changePicture() {
        var _myImg = document.getElementById("myImage");
        _myImg.src = "http://www.google.com/logos/2012/klimt12-hp.jpg";
        fadeIn(_myImg, 1000);
    }

    var _myImg = document.getElementById("myImage");
    fadeOut(_myImg, 1000, changePicture);

});
```